# delete doesn't free memory at the end of a function

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, free

I'm nearing my wits end with this. I have searched for hours for a solution to this, but I haven't found something that solves my problem.

So I want to code a neuronal network and I have written extensive code for it and which I have checked and debugged so far. I tried evolving my network over multiple generations but although it does execute it gives me a double free or corruption error. I have traced the error with valgrind to this function

```
bool mutate_a_neuron(Neuron* neuron, int numberofneurons, int numberofinputs){

    int num_e = 3*NUM_I+3;
    bool* element_already_mutated = new bool[num_e];  //line 91
    //bool element_already_mutated[15]; //Workaround :(
    for(int i =0; i<num_e; i++){
        element_already_mutated[i]=false;
    }

    int number_of_elements = (int) neuron->numberofelementstomutate;
    unsigned short will_it_be_mutated = rand() % USHRT_MAX ;

    if(  neuron->mutationrate > will_it_be_mutated ){

        for(int i = 0; i<number_of_elements; i++){

            int elementtomutate = rand() % num_e;   //choose random element
            if(element_already_mutated[elementtomutate]){//check if mutated
                i--;
                continue;
            }

            if( mutate_element(neuron, elementtomutate, numberofneurons, numberofinputs) ){//mutate stuff
                element_already_mutated[elementtomutate]=true;
            } else {    
                printf("Something went wrong while mutating an element or takes_input was false\n"); //die if error
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    delete [] element_already_mutated; //line 120

    return false;
}
```

Valgrind gives me a mismatched free()/delete/delete[] error at where element_already_mutated gets initialized and free'd. The funky thing is, if I comment the dynamic allocation out and just initialize my "workaround" which is just a normal static array, I get no memory leaks and everything gets deallocated correctly. NUM_I is defined as 4 in the header as:

```
#define NUM_I 4
```

Valgrind error:

```
==1887== 15,023,190 bytes in 1,001,546 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==1887==    at 0x4C2C93F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
==1887==    by 0x10A461: mutate_a_neuron(Neuron*, int, int) (n.cpp:91) 
==1887==    (here follow more functions, which call mutate_a_neuron)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I don't think I'm deallocating incorrectly but I have no idea where the error might be otherwise.

Comment: you are calling `delete[]` after a (potential) `return` - it won't be executed in case the `if` block is hit

Comment: just dont do dynamic memory stuff manually, but use `std::vector`

Comment: `bool* element_already_mutated = new bool[num_e];` - Change that to `std::vector<bool> element_already_mutated(num_e);`, then remove the `for` loop initializing the vector and the `delete []` statement.  Even the premature `return true` will now be harmless since `vector` will automatically destroy itself.

Comment: Your comment `//die if error` is lying.

Comment: *I have searched for hours for a solution to this, but I haven't found something that solves my problem.* -- If this is the case, a lot of this has to do with the bad C++ code you may be linking to, or the ill-taught classes / tutorials you've run into.  The solution is to use `std::vector` and never think about `new[] / delete[]` unless you have a viable reason to use it.

Comment: Since you mention `num_e` is a constant, why use a dynamically allocated array at all?  Your "workaround" seems like the better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sometimes delete it, and sometimes don't. This is the primary reason this whole method of coding is strongly discouraged. Here is your code with some extra stuff removed so you can see it more clearly:

```
bool mutate_a_neuron(...){
    bool* element_already_mutated = new bool[num_e];

    if( condition ){
        // not deleted
        return true;
    }

    delete [] element_already_mutated;
    return false;
}
```

edit: actually UnholySheep already mentioned this in the comments. I missed that.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it. I thought I was missing something very obvious but couldn't find it for the love of me.

Answer (score 1):

Given the function you did show, the simplest way to avoid the memory leak (if this function is indeed the only one leaking memory) is to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
#include <vector>

bool mutate_a_neuron(Neuron* neuron, int numberofneurons, int numberofinputs){
    int num_e = 3*NUM_I+3;
    std::vector<bool> element_already_mutated(num_e);
    int number_of_elements = (int) neuron->numberofelementstomutate;
    unsigned short will_it_be_mutated = rand() % USHRT_MAX ;
    //...
    // rest of your code
    //
    // delete [] element_already_mutated is no longer needed
    return false;
}
```

1) The initialization of the `vector` elements to `false` is automatically done on construction of the vector, thus the `for` loop that initialized the boolean array to `false` is no longer needed.

2) The call to `delete [] element_already_mutated;` must be removed, since `element_already_mutated` is no longer a pointer.  In addition, `vector` will automatically deallocate memory it has allocated, thus another reason to remove the `delete []`.

3) The `return true;` statement you had no longer will cause an issue, since if the `mutate_a_neuron` function returns for any reason, the `vector<bool>` will be destroyed, thus removing any chance of a memory leak.

4) Since the code that uses `vector` makes accesses using `[]`, the rest of the code does not need to be changed, since `std::vector` overloads `operator []` to act as an array.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. I'll probably use vectors in the future to avoid missing delete's. I used manual allocation and deallocation extensively in my code so this time I'll probably go with a delete. Is a vector faster than allocating a new array? It needs to be dynamic because I'm working on changing NUM_I to a variable.

Comment: Note that if your code in that loop throws an exception, the `delete[]` is completely missed, thus the memory leak still would exist.  Also, a vector is no slower than allocating a new array, at least in your case.  Third, a `vector<bool>` is specialized in that the amount of memory allocated for the `bool`'s is minimized to basically a "bit vector", thus saving memory.  In your `new bool[]` you're allocating `num_e * sizeof(bool)` bytes, while a vector would more than likely allocate `num_e / 8 + 1` bytes.  And of course, a vector is dynamic.

Comment: I tested it. Using std::vector makes my programm run approximately 7-10 times slower than using manual dynamic allocation (and deallocation). I read that that vector internally also uses dynamic allocation so in the best case scenario it would run about as fast as dynamic array allocation. But seeing that I use this mutate function millions of times per neural block I need to go with speed, so in this case  manual deallocation. I can't afford to be lazy with with my arrays if it eats into computing power.

Comment: @KeyaKersting Did you run an optimized build?  I bet you didn't.  What compiler options did you use?  If you're running an unoptimized or "debug" build, the timings you're seeing are meaningless.  If the compiler is *gcc*, the compiler options is `-O2` or `-O3`.  If it's Visual Studio, then run a "Release" build, not a "Debug" build.

Comment: @KeyaKersting Also, *never* time an unoptimized build, even if you are not using vector.  Too many posters fall into the trap of saying "this or that is slow", and then when informed to turn on optimizations, the program runs at the expected speed (and many times, the question gets deleted by the poster).